# Unable to target ID after navigating back to first page from second page in jQuery Mobile Single Page Model

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am just beginning with jquery mobile but have experience in jquery and javascript and I seem to be experiencing difficulties with things being refreshed, not loaded, or loaded in the DOM.

Basically I have a 2 page document that have binded tap and change events to each. On both page 1 and page 2 a tap event calls the same function which is already loaded in the head of the document. I am not having issues with the function not being called yet my issue lies within the function and it appears to relate to the loaded DOM.

Here is the function:

```
function changeStatus(e) {
        fstatus=$("#"+e).prop('title');
        sID=$("#"+e).attr('rel');

        if (fstatus == 'Pass') {
            fstatus = 'Fail';

            $("#studentColor_"+sID).css("background-color","#FCD1C5").css("border-color","#900");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#FCD1C5");

        } else if (fstatus == '') {

            fstatus = 'Pass';
            $("#studentColor_"+sID).css("background-color","#C5FCC5").css("border-color","#248703");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#C5FCC5");

        } else if (fstatus == 'Fail') {

            fstatus = '';
            $("#studentColor_"+sID).css("background-color","#FFF").css("border-color","#FFF");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#FFF");

        }

    $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").prop("title",fstatus);
    $("#studentColor_"+sID).prop("title",fstatus);

    }
```

Upon entering page 1 for the first time the tap event fires as normal and all the css styles are changed correctly. Moving to page 2 the event fires however none of the css styles work, yet it sets the title correctly. Move back to page 1 and now it behaves as it did on page 2.

So from what I understand.. on initial page load of 1, page 2 is not in the DOM so `$("#studentList"+sID+"_link")` does not exist yet the function works completely fine. Upon moving to page 2 `$("#studentList"+sID+"_link")` does exist and is visible, and `$("#studentColor_"+sID)` which was loaded in page 1 is still in the DOM. (this is not a single page app)

Is this correct?

If the error is occurring because one of those elements don't exist anymore then wouldn't it make sense that the function would not work correctly even on the initial page load of page 1? (since the element on page 2 hasn't ever been loaded)

Also it works completely fine on a browser yet when put on mobile is when the styles stop working.

It seems that the only thing that is messing up in the function is the css() call. I hope my explanation makes sense as it baffles me..

Thanks for any help.

Additional info as requested:
It is 2 HTML documents. Both generated with a bit of php.

Here is how the elements are generated on page 1: (of course I cut out the sql calls etc)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{           

if ($row['passFail'] == '') {
    $completionStatus='';
} else if ($row['passFail'] == 'P') {
$completionStatus='Pass';   
} else if ($row['passFail'] == 'F') {
$completionStatus='Fail';   
}

        if ($completionStatus=='Pass') {
            $bordercolor="#248703";
            $backgroundcolor='#C5FCC5';
        } else if ($completionStatus=='Fail') {
            $bordercolor="#900";
            $backgroundcolor='#FCD1C5';
        } else if ($completionStatus == '') {
            $bordercolor="#CCC";
            $backgroundcolor='#FFF';
        }
echo '<div class="draggable" style="text-align:center; width:50px; position:relative; font-size:.7em; top:'.$row['studentY'].'px; left:'.$row['studentX'].'px;" title="'.$completionStatus.'" rel="'.$row['ID'].'" id="student_'.$row['ID'].'"><div class="round shadow draggable_student" id="studentColor_'.$row['ID'].'" style="position: relative; background-color:'.$backgroundcolor.'; border:1px solid '.$bordercolor.'; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:3px; width:40px; height:35px; padding:0px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; padding-top:5px; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer;" title="'.$completionStatus.'"></div>'.$row[$_SESSION['student_identifier']].'</div>';
}
```

Here is how they are loaded into page 2:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{           

if ($row['passFail'] == '') {
    $completionStatus='';
} else if ($row['passFail'] == 'P') {
$completionStatus='Pass';   
} else if ($row['passFail'] == 'F') {
$completionStatus='Fail';   
}

        if ($completionStatus=='Pass') {
            $bordercolor="#248703";
            $backgroundcolor='background-color:#C5FCC5;';
        } else if ($completionStatus=='Fail') {
            $bordercolor="#900";
            $backgroundcolor='background-color:#FCD1C5;';
        } else if ($completionStatus == '') {
            $bordercolor="#CCC";
            $backgroundcolor='background-color:#FFF;';
        }
        if ($completionStatus == '') {
            $readonly=' readonly';
        } else {
            $readonly='';
        }
        if ($row['asID']=='') {
            $cc++;
            $row['asID']=time()+$cc;
        }
echo '<li><a href="#" style="'.$backgroundcolor.'" id="studentList'.$row['ID'].'_link"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td class="student_infoLink" id="student'.$row['ID'].'_td" title="'.$completionStatus.'" rel="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['student_firstName'].' '.$row['student_lastName'].'</td><td align="right" width="10%"><input type="text" placeholder="Score" rel="'.$row['asID'].'" id="student'.$row['ID'].'_score" value="'.$row['score'].'" class="updateOnChange"'.$readonly.'><div style="padding:13px; text-align:center; display:none;"><img src="preloader.gif" width="56" height="21" border="0" /></div></td></tr></table></a><a href="#edit" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Edit Student</a></li>';

}
```

Please disregard all the inline styles as most will be removed once I get this fixed up.

Listeners being bound:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $(function () {
        function tapHandler(event) {
            changeStatus($(this).attr("id"));
        }
        $(".student_infoLink").unbind("tap");
        $(".draggable").unbind("tap");
        $(".draggable").bind("tap", tapHandler);
        $(".student_infoLink").bind("tap", tapHandler);
    });
});
```

---

Workaround:

I am able to work around this issue with the following... by removing the call to the ID and searching off class. See below. I still would be appreciative of any help as to why the ID calls would not work. Much thanks to Omar for the help!

```
function changeStatus(e) {
        fstatus=$(e).prop('title');
        sID=$(e).attr('rel');

        if (fstatus == 'Pass') {
            fstatus = 'Fail';

            $(e).find(".draggable_student").css("background-color","#FCD1C5").css("border-color","#900");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#FCD1C5");

        } else if (fstatus == '') {

            fstatus = 'Pass';
            $(e).find(".draggable_student").css("background-color","#C5FCC5").css("border-color","#248703");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#C5FCC5");

        } else if (fstatus == 'Fail') {

            fstatus = '';
            $(e).find(".draggable_student").css("background-color","#FFF").css("border-color","#FFF");
            $("#studentList"+sID+"_link").css("background-color","#FFF");

        }


    $("#student"+sID+"_td").prop("title",fstatus);
    $(e).prop("title",fstatus);

    }

$(document).on('pageinit', function(e) {
console.log("pageinit is fired");
var pagecreated = e.target;



function tapHandler( event ){

changeStatus($(this)); 

}

$(".student_infoLink", pagecreated).unbind("tap");
$(".draggable", pagecreated).unbind("tap");
$(".draggable", pagecreated).bind("tap", tapHandler);
$(".student_infoLink", pagecreated).bind("tap", tapHandler);
});
```

I assume now that this works that the calling the ID was the issue... Any reasons why?

Comment: Are you using same IDs in both pages?

Comment: No different IDs on the pages. There isn't any duplicate IDs. That does make me think though that since the data-dom-cache is set to false would that mean that the page is loaded twice into the DOM when going back to page 1 from page 2? Even that doesn't solve the issue on the initial page load of 2 though

Comment: Can you add more details, html markup and whether pages are separate HTML files or are within same file. **Edit**: If you're using _Single Page Model_ (Separate files) only first page will be cached, rest of pages loaded via Ajax are removed once you navigate to a different location.

Comment: Added the requested info above. thanks. it is a Single Page Model..

Comment: Great, now your main JS code is loaded in first page? both pages? How are you attaching event listeners?

Comment: its loaded on both pages in the head and the listeners are bound in a pageinit. I will add that above as well

Comment: you dont need to wrap code in `$(function()` remove it, `pageinit` is enough. I want you to test code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s2j6fbvh/ let me know what you get.

Comment: That fixed the issue with page 2.. page 1 initial load = works, pagge 2 initial load = works, page 1 after initial load = does not work, page 2 after initial load = works.. got me closer. thanks!

Comment: "_page 1 after initial load = does not work_" means navigating back to page 1 from page2? Note that `pageinit` will fire whenever you navigate to page 2, it removes previous bindings and then attach them again.

Comment: correct... navigating back to page 2 from page 1 and the css styles do not work anymore. Just checked and doing a page refresh with changePage() on page 1 kills out the styles as well however all the rest of the function continues to work properly

Comment: Made a work around that seems to test fine... still doesn't solve the ID issue but will suffice if no better solution. Thanks for the help Omar!

Comment: Another possible solution is to give each page an ID and run `pageinit` for each page separately. Not a clean one, but I'm unable to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Btw, how do you navigate between pages? Anchors or changePage with reload option?

Comment: I don't know if that is any messier than searching by class as my work around does. Being that the ID seems to be the issue and not a .css() call I am going to edit the title of the post to make it more relevant.

Comment: anchors on those pages however i have a manual refresh button that uses changePage with the reload

Comment: Try the code without refreshing. And navigate without reloading, and console.log retrieved ID on tap/click to know whether you're targeting the correct button. Search for it in dom. Maybe you should add `var` before status and id variables to redefine them.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, short answer... use classes instead of id when targeting an element. With the DOM loading multiple pages, selecting on an ID can get a bit whacky. See workaround above in edited post.